# Show that exists a canonical symplectomorphism $T^{*}E^{*}\cong T^{*}E$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, geometric-topology, symplectic-geometry

I need to prove that for $\pi: E → M$   a vector bundle then exists a canonical symplectomorphism $T^{*}E^{*}\cong T^{*}E$.  I star with definitions: Let be  $\pi : E → M$ a  vector bundle, $\pi$ is a continuous surjection,
for every $x\in M$ then $\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$ has the vectorial structure  and it is finite dimensional and such that: every point in $M$ there is a neighborhood $U$, there is $ n$ natural number and some diffeomorphism

${\displaystyle \varphi \colon U\times {\mathbb {R} }^{n}\to \pi ^{-1}(U)}$
such that for all $x\in U$

- $\pi φ(x, v) = x$ for all $v\in R^{n}$
- the app $ v\rightarrow  φ(x, v)$ is a ismomorphism between  $ R^{n}$ and $π^{-1}(\{x\})$.

The other side we have that a symplectomorphism is a diffeomorphism between two symplectic manifolds $(M,\omega)$ and $(N,\omega')$ such that

$f^{*}\omega '=\omega$ where $f^{*}$ is the pullback of $f$

Besides, $E^{*}$ is the dual of $E$ and $T^{*}E^{*}$ represent the pullback bundle.

Now i guess that i need to show that exists some function $g: (T^{*}E^{*},\omega_1)\to (T^{*}E,\omega_2)$ such that $g^{*}\omega_2=\omega_1$, so how can to start or how i need to define $g$?

$E^{*}$ and $T^{*}E^{*}$ are simplectic manifolds and i guess that $T^{*}:E^{*}\to E$ such that $T^{*}E^{*}=\{(h,e)\in E^{*}\times E : g(h)=\pi(e)\}$  am I right? This excersise is very difficult to me, i dont know how to start, please can give me hints?

Thank you.

**Note:** I am not sure about my definitions about $T^{*}E^{*}$ just it was intuition but i will appreciate if somebody can help me understand this point too.

The other side i found some recipe and i attach next, where an 1-form tautological is $\alpha= \sum \xi_i dx_i$ with $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are coordinates in $U\subset E$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n,\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n$ are coordinates of $T^{*}E$ for example and the canonical 2-form is given by $$\omega=\sum d\xi_i\wedge dx_i$$ The book is Lectures on symplectic geometric , Ana Cannas Da Silva. Even this i am stuck i do not how to proceed. [image]

As a @Chris H said before, when the bundle is trivial we have the following:

$T^{*}E$ is isomorphism with $$T^{*}M \times \mathbb{R^{n}}\times \mathbb {R^{n^{*}}}$$ and

$T^{*}E^{*}$ is isomorphism with $$T^{*}M \times \mathbb{R^{n^{*}}}\times \mathbb{R^{n}}$$

then the canonical forms in $T^{*}E$ and $T^{*}E^{*}$ can be describe by $$\sum^{n}dx_i\wedge dy_i +dr_i\wedge ds_i$$ and $$\sum^{n}dx_i\wedge dy_i +ds_i\wedge dr_i$$. Therefore, we can define a difeomorphism by
$$\phi:T^{*}E\to T^{*}E^{*} $$ by  $\phi(x,y,s,r)=(x,y,r,s)$ and this satisfies that $\phi^{*}\omega_1=\omega_0$.

How can continued by the general case?

Thank you

Comment: i haven't thought about the full problem yet, but your description of $T^*E^*$ as a pullback bundle is not correct. Generally, $T^*X$ for any smooth manifold $X$ is the cotangent bundle of $X$. In your case, you start with a bundle $E \to X$ whose total space is some smooth manifold $E$. You can consider the dual bundle, $E^*\to X$ whose total space is some other smooth manifold. Then you can consider the cotangent bundles of these spaces, $T^*E^*$ and $T^*E$, and the question asks you to relate these cotangent bundles. Are you familiar with the cotangent bundle construction?

Comment: Thank  you @staedtlerr, No really, i am beginner with all this, but i appreciate any hint to start, can you help me with other hint please?

Comment: It might help to first solve the problem when $M$ is a single point. Then you want a canonical symplectomorphism between $T^* V$ and $T^* V^*$ where $V$ is a vector space. It feels to me like they both might be isomorphic to $V\oplus V^*$, perhaps writing this down precisely could help with the general case.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisH i will try with your help!!!